# ffmpeg - generating thumbs results in different aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg

My ffmpeg command looks like

```
ffmpeg -i "/tmp/assets/input.mov" -y -ss 00:00:05 -vf fps=1/5,scale=300:-1 /tmp/output/thumbs/thumb%03d.jpg
```

input.mov has a display resolution of 16:9 even though the source resolution looks to be 1440x1080. i.e. the video plays in a player at 16:9 (not really sure how this happens)

the generated thumbs in this case are 300x225 (4:3) and look distorted.

How can i have it generate the thumb according to the display aspect ratio? I was hoping for 300x169 (16:9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i "/tmp/assets/input.mov" -y -ss 00:00:05 -vf fps=1/5,scale=300:ow/dar,setsar=1 /tmp/output/thumbs/thumb%03d.jpg
```

> *the video plays in a player at 16:9 (not really sure how this happens)*

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50347465/

Comment: SAR is equivalent to storage aspect ratio, in lots of cases it's a technique used in shooting with anamorphic lens to achieve 2.39:1 or even 3.5:1 ratio, the resulting is a condensed image. DAR is for achieving the correct image display, the formula is simple SAR × PAR = DAR but you need to know your footage & video standards.

Comment: gah, i meant it's used to calculate _result_ of technique of shooting with [...], which shots are perceptually look condensed but the data is intact.